# make write function to Firestore happen on button first click

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I have a row that shows the weight and reps done, this is edited by clicking update which then changes the div to input the reps and weight. When the button is clicked to save the values, the divs swap back to normal but the values are only saved to Firestore after clicking the button twice.

how do I correct my JS function to only click the button once and save the firestore write and then swap the divs

```
document.getElementById("set-one-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("set-one-read");
    var y = document.getElementById("set-one-edit");
    var b = document.getElementById("set-one-button");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "none";
        b.innerHTML = "Update";
    } else {
        const rewriteProgrammeSets = doc(db, "uuid", uid, "programme", id, "exercises", ex);
        const setActivityHistory = doc(db, "uuid", uid, "activity", "history", "past-workouts", id, "exercises", ex, "sets", "sets-one");

        const oneRep = document.getElementById("oneRepData").value
        const oneWeight = document.getElementById("oneWeightData").value

        updateDoc(rewriteProgrammeSets, {
            oneRep: oneRep,
            oneWeight: oneWeight,
        }).then(function () {
            setDoc(setActivityHistory, {
                order: "1",
                reps: oneRep,
                weight: oneWeight,
            })
            console.log("Saved");
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        }).finally(function () {
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.style.display = "block";
            b.innerHTML = "Save";
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you run the code in the debugger already? Set a breakpoint on `if (x.style.display === "none") {` and check the value of `x.style.display`, as that determines what branch it goes into. --- If that doesn't explain, set breakpoint on the other lines too, and check each variable on each line to see if it is what you expect it to be.